# How to translate information written into text form to javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my attempt at my question

I have a search box (HTML):

```
<form method="post">
    Search:<input type="text" name="search">
    <input value="Search" type="submit">
</form>
```

I then have php:

```
$search =  $_POST["search"];
```

And then Jquery:

```
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('li:contains("    /* I want this part to be the bit entered by the form... $search */   ")').css( "color", "red" );
});
```

But I can't seem to get the php into jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var my_php_var = <?php echo json_encode($search) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    var foundin = $('li:contains("<?php echo $search; ?>").css("color", "red");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing it to :

```
$(function() {
    var foundin = $('li:contains(" <?php echo $search ?> ")').css( "color", "red" );
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me. If there isn't a `li` that goes with the search can you get an `alert("Not Found")`